# Why has Tian Ji'an's wife ordered to kill Nie Yinniang's uncle in "The Assassin"?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-assassin

In "The Assassin" (2015) killing Tien Xing, Yinniang's uncle, does not seem to be of any benefit to Lady Tian, Tian Ji'an's wife. Yet it seems that it was her, who ordered to bury Tien Xing alive. Why did she do that?